# JBoss Richfaces ModalPanel - condition based invokation

Tags: jsf

I am using JBoss Richfaces
and I need to invoke rich:modalPanel
when a particular condition happens.

The sample code is here--

This is the modalpanel

```
<rich:modalPanel  id="show_alert" height="125" width="325" zindex="2000">
                <h:outputText value="shamik testing"/><br/>
                <a4j:commandButton value="#{uiLabel.no}" onclick="#             {rich:component('show_alert')}.hide()" styleClass="button"/>
</rich:modalPanel>
```

I want to show the modal panel when someone clicks this link.

```
<a4j:commandLink value="#{uiLabel.config_ret}" id = "aaa"

actionListener="#{aging.configureRetention}"                            reRender="cp_tab_form">
<rich:componentControl for="show_alert" attachTo="aaa" operation="show" event="onclick"/>           
</a4j:commandLink>
```

I am trying to make operation="#{bean.cond}" so that the name of the operation comes dynamically. But does not working.

I want to call operation = hide when bean.cond = false
and operation = show when bean.cond = true.

I might be doing something very stupid here :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for posting it.. I was not rerendering the commandLink :-( sorry for it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at using the "data" attribute of the a4j:commandLink to return the value of the bean.cond